# open link to another div in the same page (php)

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to ask about open link to another div in the same page (php).

The situation is like this:

I divide a page into 2 section top and button

```
<div id="top">
</div>
<div id="buttom">
</div>
```

I put some thumbnails at the bottom and when I click the thumbs it's will play a video on the top section. How to do that?

Comment: all of these can be achieved using javascript.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, and everything with Javascript.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you're asking others to do your work for you

Comment: removed "php" Tag

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

**your.php**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">

</div>
<div id="buttom">

<div id="t1"> open_html </div>
<div id="t2"> play_youtube </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#t1").click(function(){
    $("#top").load('video.html');
});

$("#t2").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('top').innerHTML='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uelHwf8o7_U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
});


    
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #top{
        width: 560px;
        height: 315px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #buttom{
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
```

**video.html**

```
<h1>This is video.html!</h1>
```

Comment: Yeeeaaahh its works.. but now how to align the buttom div horizontally?

Comment: Please don't encourage these kind of questions on this site by doing others work for them. It's off-topic and it'll invite downvotes